# protractor select element by.cssContainingText no element found

Tags: protractor

I want to select a clickable text link in a jqwidget table. Below is the element:

```
<div class="jqx-grid-cell-left-align">
 <a onclick="showDetails(1)" class="customer-name-link">Auto Opportunity</a> 
</div>
```

I have tried as following, but I get "No element found using locator" error.

```
element(by.cssContainingText('.customer-name-link', 'Auto Opportunity')).click();
```

What did I do wrong and how to select this element?

Thanks

Comment: Your code correct,  did you try sleep a long time before click to see we need to wait page load.

Comment: can you also try `element(by.linkText('Auto Opportunity'))` and see if this works?

Comment: @yong Oh sorry I didn't know I'd need a sleep for this. I'm very new to protractor. I just tried browser.waitForAngular(); but it still can't find the element.

Comment: I mean adding `browser.sleep(15* 1000) // sleep 15 seconds` before the click. It's only for debug purpose, please replace it to `browser.wait` if it work

Answer (score 0):

You can add waiting for element to be visible

```
var EC = protractor.ExpectedConditions;

browser.wait(EC.visibilityOf(element(by.cssContainingText('.customer-name-link', 'Auto Opportunity')), 30000, "element is not visible").then(function() {
    element(by.cssContainingText('.customer-name-link', 'Auto Opportunity')).click();
});
```